# defined constant result to name instead of value php

Tags: php, function, command

I am experiencing a weird undefined constant on my production server. This code below works on my staging server.

```
<?php
  define('KEY_ENCRYPTION','12345678');
  echo KEY_ENCRYPTION;
?>
```

The result of the code above on my staging server is **12345678** while on my production server is **KEY_ENCRYPTION**.

Can you help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: You made sure that what you see is _not_ a cached result?

Comment: yes am 100% sure @arkascha

Comment: Very strange. You should at least have an entry in your http servers error log file in that case. What does it say?

Comment: @arkascha PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant KEY_ENCRYPTION - assumed ... yeah strange

Comment: Very strange indeed, if you really test with the exact two lines of code you posted above... It _is_ possible to remove builtin functions from php, but _very_ rare. Also in that case you would have gotten a "function not defined" error... And special php version you installed on your production system?

Comment: Do the production and staging servers have the same PHP Version? The same php.ini conf?

Comment: Same PHP version but not the same php.ini configuration. Not sure where to look which maybe related to constant define.